# What is the syntax to a templated recursive function?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

This is driving me round the bend at the moment. As a homebrew exercise I wanted to template a recursive call in a class. in the .h file I have:

```
template <typename T1> 

    class BinaryTree 
    {
    public:
        BinaryTree(T1 element);
        ~BinaryTree();

    BinaryTree* addLeftLeaf(BinaryTree<T1>* node);
```

etc...

then in the .cpp

```
template <typename T1> BinaryTree* BinaryTree<T1>::addLeftLeaf(BinaryTree<T1>* node)
{
    return node;
}
```

I've tried seemingly loads of ideas but thus far nothing. Just errors like error C2955: 'BinaryTree' : use of class template requires template argument list

Any suggestions would be kindly appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: The error is the return type is not templated. But Template code (in general) needs to be in header file. So just put the whole thing inside the class definition and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the source file, you need to specify `BinaryTree<T1>` instead of just `BinaryTree`. i.e.

```
template <typename T1>
BinaryTree<T1>* BinaryTree<T1>::addLeftLeaf(BinaryTree<T1>* node)
{
    return node;
}
```

You can only refer to a template without its parameter list within the class/struct body.

---

Beware also that generally it's a bad idea to have non-specialized templates in `.cpp` files because that means people won't be able to implicitly instantiate them (without `#include`ing the `.cpp`).

As a rule of thumb, only specialized templates should go in the `.cpp`. Non-specialized templates should live in the `.h`.

If you know what you are doing and plan on manually instantiating the templates then by all means put the body in the `.cpp`, but generally that isn't what people do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a template function definition in the .cpp file, it has to be in the .h file :)

also, Peter Alexander is right about needing the edit to that function definition in the source, I'll leave that to his answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

The return type is not complete, it requires the template argument as well.